What are these wall textures?
These are the areas I need help with




Recreating wall texture is more of an art than a science.  The three posted pics look like an orange-peel texture done very runny, then rolled over with a very fluffy roller.
These textures must be sprayed with texture guns, not with spray cans. The idea is to spray about 3 to 4 feet away with very runny compound, (just slightly thicker than water.) Then roll over the spray on the wall lightly. This gives the "saggy" look.
Any of the textures takes practice.  Get a big piece of scrap drywall and spray away.

Agree that this probably came from a hopper/ gun application with runny texture. It might not have even been touched with a roller afterwards.

@Ad, The last pic looks like alot of just sag, but the top 2 pics look like there is too much uniformity to not have been rolled.  But this is educated guessing at it's best.
